# Necesito hacer un programa en C que muestre 100 numeros aleatorios entre 500 y 800 que sean diferentes, y no se como hacer que sean diferentes

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int N,a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(a=1;a<=100;a++) {
        N=rand() % 500 +300;
        printf("%d.- %d \n",a,N);
    }
}
```

Comment: A ver, piénsalo un poco. Si a un número le aplicas `%500`... ¿en qué rango de números están los posibles resultados?

Answer (score 2):

Tu algoritmo para generar números aleatorios en el rango (500-800) es incorrecto:

- `X = rand() % 500` obtiene un número en el rango (0,500)
- `N = X + 300` obtiene un número en el rango (300-800)

Deberías invertir los valores:

```
N = (rand() % 300) + 500;
//            ^^^    ^^^
//          rango    offset
```

Por otro lado, para garantizar que los números sean diferentes tienes que almacenarlos en algún sitio... y para eso nada mejor que un arreglo:

```
#define MAX_NUMEROS 100

int numeros[MAX_NUMEROS] = { 0 };

for(a=0;a<MAX_NUMEROS;a++)
{
  // generamos un numero
  N = (rand() % 300) + 500;

  // comprobamos si el numero ya esta siendo utilizado
  for( int i=0; i<a; i++ )
  {
    if( numeros[i] == N )
    {
      N = 0; // Numero repetido, lo reseteamos
      break;
    }
  }

  if( N != 0 ) // Si el numero ha pasado las validaciones, lo insertamos
  {
    numeros[a] = N;
    printf("%d.- %d \n",a,N);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de pintarlos en el for, vete guardando todos los números generados en un Array, y cada vez que generes uno nuevo recorres ese será y yo compruebas que no exista, si no existe lo guardas en el array, si existe pasas al siguiente, así hasta que el array tenga 100 números.

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede ayudar a solucionar tu problema :

https://foro.elhacker.net/programacion_cc/programa_que_genera_numeros_aleatorios_sin_repetir_en_c-t428450.0.html